# conversion error while converting a decimal value. the record which has more precision are not converting

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm converting a decimal value with has more than precision which I am converting to

```
select convert(numeric(8,4),17597.9)
```

I need to convert this value what is the alternative

Comment: Please do not request (in questions or comments) a speed of response. Volunteers will respond when they can.

Comment: Please read and understand [Precision](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: You cannot convert that value to that type.  It doesn't fit.

Comment: Your value fits if we're dealing with floating point. Unfortunately you want a type with a fixed decimal.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the *precision* of the value, but the *scale*.

[The documentation says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> s (scale): 
>   The number of decimal digits that are stored to the right of the decimal point. This number is subtracted from p to determine the maximum number of digits to the left of the decimal point. Scale must be a value from 0 through p, and can only be specified if precision is specified. The default scale is 0 and so 0 <= s <= p. Maximum storage sizes vary, based on the precision.

You've specified a datatype of precision 8, scale 4 - which means that you can have at most 8 digits total, with 4 digits to the right of the decimal point - and by extension of that, a max of 4 digits to the left.

If you want to convert that number, you'll need a to specify a precision `p >= s + 5`, such as `numeric(9,4)`

```
select convert(numeric(9,4),17597.9)

-- 17597.9000
```